# Why do I get this error when trying to get my past paypal transactions?

Tags: node.js, rest, curl, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to read my past transactions. I have already done that with the curl tool, but I can't get it working in nodeJS. I am trying this with the request api. Getting the token from paypal works just fine. Just can't figure out to do this

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2020-05-20T01:01:01-00:00&end_date=2020-06-19T01:01:01-00:00 \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer access-token"
```

in NodeJS currently I have this. Can someone help me pls figuring it out?

```
var request = require('request');

let token;

request.post({
    uri: "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    auth: {
        'user': client_id,
        'pass': secret,
    },
    form: {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    let resp = JSON.parse(body);
    token = resp.access_token;
    console.log(token)
    if (error)
        console.log(error)

    getTransactions();
});


function getTransactions() {
    if (!token) {
        console.error("Could not get token");
        return;
    }


    request.post({
        uri: "https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2020-05-20T01:01:01-00:00&end_date=2020-06-19T01:01:01-00:00",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        auth: {
            bearer: token,
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
        console.log(error)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))

    });
}
```

The Error:

```
"statusCode":404,"body":"","headers":{"content-length":"0",
"connection":"close","date":"Sun, 21 Jun 2020 00:35:15 GMT",
"cache-control":"max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
"paypal-debug-id":"207f5d4c9341",
"strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,
"host":"api.paypal.com","port":443,"hostname":"api.paypal.com",
"hash":null,
"search":"?start_date=2020-05-20T01:01:01-00:00&end_date=2020-06-19T01:01:01-00:00",
"query":"start_date=2020-05-20T01:01:01-00:00&end_date=2020-06-19T01:01:01-00:00",
"pathname":"/v1/reporting/transactions",
"path":"/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2020-05-20T01:01:01-00:00&end_date=2020-06-19T01:01:01-00:00",
"href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2020-05-20T01:01:01-00:00&end_date=2020-06-19T01:01:01-00:00"},
"method":"POST","headers":{"Accept":"application/json",
"Accept-Language":"en_US","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"authorization":"Bearer accesstoken_is_my_little_secret",
"content-length":0}}}
        index.js:38
```

Answer (score 1):

Your NodeJS is sending a POST request instead of a GET, hence the 404

Comment: How would I transmit my access code if not with post and why does the token one then work?

Comment: The access token goes in a HTTP header. The token POST call works because it is *supposed* to be a POST call.